# jQuery `.attr()` is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get values of specific option tags using jQuery.

This is my HTML:

```
<select name="modele" class="wyszselect" onchange="przenies(this[this.selectedIndex].value);">
   <option value="0">Choose model</option>
   <option value="242">242</option>
   <option value="243">243</option>
   <option value="244">244</option>
   <option value="246">246</option>
   <option value="320">320</option>
   <option value="324">324</option>
   <option value="328">328</option>
   <option value="33">33</option>
</select>
```

This is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var options = [];
    $("option").each(function (index, oneOption) {
          options.push(oneOption.attr("value"))
    });
    console.log(options);
});
```

I got this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: oneOption.attr is not a function

Comment: `oneOption` is a dom object, `.attr()` is a jquery function. You could use `oneOption.value`

Answer (score 4):

Conver `oneOption` to `jQuery` Object, like so

```
 $("option").each(function (index, oneOption) {
      options.push($(oneOption).attr("value"))
 });
```

[`Example`](http://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/bs3he6nL/)

Answer (score 3):

The each function will pass the `DOM` object instead of `jQuery` object. Either convert to jQuery object or use the DOM object, like `options.push(oneOption.value)`, this will be faster then converting the DOM object to jQuery object and then calling `attr` to get the value. You can also use `this.value`

```
$("option").each(function (index, oneOption) {
      //options.push($(oneOption).attr("value"));       
      options.push(oneOption.value);
      //options.push(this.value);
});
```

For getting comma separated value

```
$("option").map(function(){
   return this.value;
}).get().join(',');
```

Comment: @RazvanDumitru do you mean to do console.log(map(options)) ?

Comment: @Adil no i mean that the console should print something like this: `optinos = ["value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", ....]`

Answer (score 1):

use `map()`in jquery() ,and get the option value using **this** object

```
options = $("option").map(function (index, oneOption) {
    return this.value;
}).get().join(',');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vmxrca1d/10/)**

or in each()

```
options =[];
$("option").each(function (index, oneOption) {
        options.push(this.value);
})
```

Comment: how can I get the result in a form separated in comma ?

Comment: join () https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Comment: your update gives me this result `0,242,243,244,246,320,324,328,33`, while i would like this result: `["value", "value", "value" ......]`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to convert it to a jQuery Element:

```
$("option").each(function (index, oneOption) {
      options.push($(oneOption).attr("value"))
 });
```